# How to upload a file in popup using Selenium remote webdriver on linux machine

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I have to automate an application and am working on Windows machine.

On clicking some button, **window popup opens** where I can choose a file or enter the path. Upload functionality is working fine using the `Robot class`. But finally scripts has to run on Linux node through Jenkins and I don't have access of those nodes. I have **2 issues** here:

1. Scripts are running on headless browser, how to handle file upload here?
2. If I am setting `options.setHeadless(false);`, will the chrome browser will run in foreground? If yes then how to handle file upload here?(As I don't have node access so can't check)

Comment: File upload should be handled the same way in headless vs. not headless. So if it works in regular Chromedriver, it should work in headless. I would not recommend setting headless to false, as this can cause unexpected browser size issues depending on the VM's configuration. Headless will bypass these issues.  Is there an error you are encountering with this approach?

Comment: try to upload file with uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\\filepath"); or else you can use auto it also

Comment: @Christine.. when I was not setting headless as false, using the robot class it was throwing java.awt.AWTException: headless environment  at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java.

Comment: @Rock... there is no text kind of field where I can set the path. Only window popup is the option.

Comment: It will be a hidden input field. That's how most file uploads are handled -- when you choose a file from your computer, you are actually sending the file path text into a hidden `<input type='file'/>` element. However, your error message is specific to Robots, and not Selenium. It's strange that your code works with a browser, but not in headless mode. This might be a better question for a robots-specific help forum -- without a Selenium exception, it's hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Christine... Thank you! hidden <input type='file'/> has solved the problem. Adding to this as script was running using remote web driver so we have to tell the local file path using,
((RemoteWebElement) obj ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); Using both script worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the file in the windows pop up using a simple Shell script that can be stored in a VBS file and then call this file once your file upload button is clicked to enter the path into the window's pop up

Sample shell code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "Your complete file path here"

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```